# conbine response return and view

Tags: laravel-5

I have two return in my controller method.
How can I combine both?

```
public function index()
{
   $data=Event::get(['title','start','color']);
   $objectifs=Objectif::all();
   $ob=Array('objectifs'=>$objectifs);
   return view('newc')->with('objectifs', $objectifs);
   return Response()->json($data);}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**we can't use '*return*' multiple times**

```
public function index() {
    $data = Event::pluck('title', 'start','color' );
    return Response()->json($data);
}
```

use another controller function

```
public function jason() { 
$ob=Array('objectifs'=>$objectifs);
return view('newc')->with(compact('ob'));
}
```

You should read this laravel docmentaion
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2

Comment: i know that i can't use 2 return i need to conbin the both returns  in the same controller

Comment: exactly i solved my problem by using 2 controllers thanx for your help

Answer (score 0):

In place of using two return you can use multiple "with" like this

```
public function index()
{
   $data=Event::get(['title','start','color']);
   $objectifs=Objectif::all();
   $ob=Array('objectifs'=>$objectifs);
   return view('newc')->with('objectifs', $objectifs)->with('data',$data);
```

Comment: with this soulution i get just the view('newc')->with('objectifs', $objectifs) but i don't get my data

Comment: you use data of $data as data variable in view